# Field multiplicative identity

Tags: field-theory

[image]

How would I find a multiplicative identity for this?

$[x, y] \cdot [a_1, b_1] = [a_1, b_1]$ is what I want. The property $1 \cdot a = a$ has to be true

Answer (score 1):

You have $$[x,y].[a,b] = [xa-yb,xb+ya] = [a,b]$$
then $\begin{cases}xa-yb = a\\xb+ya=b\end{cases}$ so $\begin{cases}(x-1)a-yb = 0\\(x-1)b+ya=0\end{cases}$,

So $(x,y) = (1,0)$.

Comment: Note that the system is true for all $(a,b)$.